# Netty server stops responding

Tags: java, netty

I have `ServerHandshakeHandler` which extends `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`. Client emulates multiple access to server. After some time of successful communication server stops responding when client tries to connect. It doesn't show any incoming connections. Client restart doesn't help, only restart of server.

I tried to set telnet connection when server stops responding: connection establishes but I can't get any response from server (when server is in normal state, it sends response). Similar situation with `nmap -v --packet-trace -sT localhost -p {port}` : nmap discovers port as open, but there is no log information about incoming connection on server.

Server:

```
public class ServerHandshakeHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

private final ChannelGroup group;
private static final byte HANDSHAKE_SUCCEDED = 1;
private static final byte HANDSHAKE_FAILED = 0;
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());


public ServerHandshakeHandler(ChannelGroup group) {
    this.group = group;
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    LOG.debug("in ServerHandshakeHandler.channelRead");
    ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
    String someField = getSomeField(buf);
    ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);

    if (someField.isEmpty()) {
        this.fireHandshakeFailed(ctx);
        return;
    }

    LOG.debug("Removing handshake handler from pipeline.");

    ctx.pipeline().remove(this);
    this.fireHandshakeSucceeded(ctx);

}

@Override
public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    LOG.debug("in ServerHandshakeHandler.channelActive, group size = " + this.group.size());
    this.group.add(ctx.channel());
    LOG.debug("Incoming connection from: {}",
            ctx.channel().remoteAddress().toString());
}

@Override
 public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    LOG.error("exception caught ", cause);
    if (ctx.channel().isActive()) {
        ctx.channel().close();
    } else {
        this.fireHandshakeFailed(ctx);
    }
}

private void fireHandshakeFailed(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    LOG.debug("fire handshake failed");
    ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.buffer(1);
    buf.writeByte(HANDSHAKE_FAILED);
    ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(buf);

    ctx.channel().close();
    ctx.fireUserEventTriggered(HandshakeEvent.handshakeFailed(ctx.channel()));
}

private void fireHandshakeSucceeded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    LOG.debug("fire handshake succeded");
    ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.buffer(1);
    buf.writeByte(HANDSHAKE_SUCCEDED);
    ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(buf);

    ctx.fireUserEventTriggered(HandshakeEvent
            .handshakeSucceeded(ctx.channel()));
}
```

}

Client:

```
public class MyClient {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
private String host;
private int port;
private Socket socket;

public Client(String host, int port) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
}

public void send(String id, String message) {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
        LOG.debug("connected to server");

        if (performHandshake(id)) {
            LOG.debug("handshake success");
            sendMessage(message);
        }
        socket.close();;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOG.error("error while sending data", ex);
    }
}

private boolean performHandshake(String id) {
    try {
        byte[] request = handshakeRequest(id);
        writeBytes(request);
        byte[] response = readBytes(1);
        return (response != null && response.length == 1 && response[0] == 1);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOG.error("perform handshake error", ex);
        return false;
    }
}

private byte[] handshakeRequest(String id) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {...}

private void writeBytes(byte[] data) throws IOException {
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    out.write(data);
}

private byte[] readBytes(int length) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
    int currentLength = 0;
    while (currentLength < length) {
        int size = in.read(buffer); //here client stops waiting server response
        if (size == -1) {
            throw new IOException("unexpected end of stream");
        }
        baos.write(buffer, 0, size);
        currentLength += size;
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED! There was narrow piece of code where I was calling synchronized function with connection to database. This connection cannot be established for some reasons and the function hangs. Thread in this function goes into [WAITING](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) state. After a while other treads try to access this function and become BLOCKED. That's why server stops processing incoming connections.

I recommend **jvisualvm** profiling tool, it helped me to find this bug.

Comment: Hi, Can you provide more insite on this issue. I'm facing a similar problem. However jvisualvm isn't showing any related threads that are waiting. Can you elaborate on your answer as to why a function waiting for database connection could've resulted in incoming connections not responding?

Comment: @BandiKishore all netty threads were trying to call one synchronized method which was hanging and all the threads were waiting for it to enter. If jvisualvm isn't showing waiting threads, possibly your issue is different from mine

Comment: hmm, I guess so. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @BandiKishore if you'll solve your problem, I think it would be useful if you'll kindly post you solution here for others :)